# unable to view pdf file in listview from external storage with android 11.12

Tags: java, android, listview, pdf, android-external-storage

I created app to load pdf file to listview from external storage. my app seems to work successfully in android 5.6. However in android 11,12 my app don't show any pdf file to list view. after searching in internet similar issues. I don't find solution for it.

in my main activity.java, I coded below:
`

```
public ArrayList<File> findPdf (File file){
    ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    if (files != null){

        for (File singleFile: files){

            try {
                if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
                    arrayList.addAll(findPdf(singleFile));
                }
                else {
                    if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")){
                        arrayList.add(singleFile);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return arrayList;

    }
    return arrayList;



}

public void displayPdf(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
    pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
    pdfList.addAll(findPdf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
    adapter = new MainAdapter(this,pdfList,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onPdfSelected(File file) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PDFwatch.class);

    intent.putExtra("path",file.getAbsoluteFile());

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

in Manifest.xml file, I added permission below:
`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and add below code in tab <application as well.

```
android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

`Please help me how to overcome this obstacle. thanks and best wish`

my app loaded successfully pdf file in listview in android 5, 6 but my app fail to show pdf file in listview in android version 11.12.. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: `but pdf file is not loaded in android 11, 12 with my code. ` Wrong problem description. Your pdf file is just not listed by .listFiles(). Why did you post so much irrelevant code?

Comment: can you help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Not if you do not agree with a wrong problem description. And not if you dont post the relevant code and not if you do not remove all irrelevant code. Your problem is just .listFiles() on File class.